# Extract last 4-digit number from a series in R using stringr

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I would like to flatten lists extracted from HTML tables.  A minimal working example is presented below.  The example depends on the `stringr` package in R.  The first example exhibits the desired behavior.

```
years <- c("2005-", "2003-")
unlist(str_extract_all(years,"[[:digit:]]{4}"))

[1] "2005" "2003"
```

The below example produces an undesirable result when I try to match the last 4-digit number in a series of other numbers.

```
years1 <- c("2005-", "2003-", "1984-1992, 1996-")
unlist(str_extract_all(years1,"[[:digit:]]{4}$"))

character(0)
```

As I understand the documentation, I should include `$` at the end of the pattern in order to request the match at the end of the string.  I would prefer to match from the second example the numbers, "2005", "2003", and "1996".

Comment: `substr(years1,1,4)` provides a list of "2005" "2003" "1984" where I would like to obtain "2005", "2003", and "1996"

Comment: How about `sub('.*(\\d{4}).*', '\\1', years1)`?

Comment: @jbaums, that definitely works, could you provide a resource/explanation for your solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `stringi` package has convenient functions that operate on specific parts of a string.  So you can find the last occurrence of four consecutive digits with the following.

```
library(stringi)

x <- c("2005-", "2003-", "1984-1992, 1996-")

stri_extract_last_regex(x, "\\d{4}")
# [1] "2005" "2003" "1996"
```

Other ways to get the same result are

```
stri_sub(x, stri_locate_last_regex(x, "\\d{4}"))
# [1] "2005" "2003" "1996"

## or, since these count as words
stri_extract_last_words(x)
# [1] "2005" "2003" "1996"

## or if you prefer a matrix result
stri_match_last_regex(x, "\\d{4}")
#      [,1]  
# [1,] "2005"
# [2,] "2003"
# [3,] "1996"
```

Comment: I often find myself looking at your posts, thinking _I really need to familiarise myself with that package_... :)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response and exposure to `stringi`

Answer (score 15):

You can use base R `sub` for this quite easily:

```
sub('.*(\\d{4}).*', '\\1', years1)

## [1] "2005" "2003" "1996"
```

The pattern to be matched here is `.*` (zero or more of any character) followed by `\\d{4}` (four consecutive numerals, which we capture by enclosing in parentheses), followed by zero or more characters.

`sub` replaces the matched pattern with the value in the second argument. In this case, `\\1` indicates that we want to replace the whole matched pattern with the first captured substring (i.e. the four consecutive numerals).

Here regex is greedy, so it will bypass early matches of `\\d{4}`, consuming them with `.*`. Only the last sequence of four consecutive numerals is captured.

Comment: This is very handy solution, I came across when faced with similar problem. How difficult would be to change the expression to match *first* four digits instead of the last ones?

Comment: @Konrad - you could do that with `sub('\\D*(\\d{4}).*', '\\1', years1)`, where `\\D*` means zero or more characters that _aren't_ numerals.

Answer (score 2):

The end of string `$` anchor asserts the position at the end of the string.

Saying, match exactly four digits at the end of the string. Unfortunately, what happens is that the digits try to get matched then the regex engine advances trying to assert that position and fails because there not at this position and consecutively backtracks trying to match them.

To fix this, you can [**greed**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap)ily consume all characters until the last set of digits.

```
years1 <- c('2005-', '2003-', '1984-1992, 1996-')
unlist(str_extract_all(years1, perl('.*\\K\\d{4}')))
# [1] "2005" "2003" "1996"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\\d{4}[^\\d]*$
```

Try this.This should do it for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/kG5pN6/2