# how to catch the last number in a sentence?

Tags: r

for example:

'I want to get 10 apples, 99 bananas and 86 oranges.'

'I want to buy a car'

What I want to do is get the last number in the sentence.
The result I m hoping is:

86

NA

How can I make it possible by using R?
thanks~

p.s. I just want to catch Arabic numerals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `str_extract` from `stringr` which is also based on `tidyverse`

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(sapply(str_extract_all(str1, "\\d+"), tail, 1))
#[1] 86 NA
```

---

Or just using only `base R`

```
as.numeric(sub(".* (\\d+).*", "\\1", str1))
#[1] 86 NA
```

---

If it is a data.frame, we extract the column and update the columns

```
df1$col1 <- as.numeric(sapply(str_extract_all(df1$col1, "\\d+"), tail, 1))
```

---

Also, we can find more resources from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28622174/extract-last-4-digit-number-from-a-series-in-r-using-stringr)

#### data

```
str1 <- c("I want to get 10 apples, 99 bananas and 86 oranges.",
    "I want to buy a car")
```

Comment: What if my data is a data.frame?

Answer (score 5):

Using `stringi` we can use `stri_extract_last_regex` which will return last matched pattern in the string.

```
as.numeric(stringi::stri_extract_last_regex(x, "\\d+"))
#[1] 86 NA
```

**data**

```
x <- c('I want to get 10 apples, 99 bananas and 86 oranges', 'I want to buy a car')
```

Comment: What if my data is a data.frame?

Comment: @recon instead of `x` use the column name then. `df$column_name`.

Comment: thank you for your reply mate but sorry that i think i should accept the answer by @akrun because he answer me first. sorry again mate.

Comment: @recon no issues, you can accept any answer of your choice :)